# Exception: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable when optimising

Tags: python, scipy, minimize

I keep getting

Exception: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

when trying to minimize a function.

I can call the function I'm trying to minimize as

```
def testLLCalc():
    mmc = MortalityModelCalibrator()
    a = mmc.log_likelihood(2000, np.array([[0.6, 0.2, 0.8]]))
```

but when I try and minimize it by doing

```
x0 = np.array([0, 0, 0])
res = minimize(-a[0], x0)
```

I get the exception above.  Any help would be appreciated.  Full traceback is:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.0Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\unittest\case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
yield
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.0Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\unittest\case.py", line 601, in run
testMethod()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.0Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\nose\case.py", line 198, in runTest
self.test(*self.arg)
File "C:\Users\Matt\Documents\PyCharmProjects\Mortality\src\PennanenMortalityModel_test.py", line 57, in testLLCalc
res = minimize(-a[0], x0)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.0Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 444, in minimize
return _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.0Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 913, in _minimize_bfgs
gfk = myfprime(x0)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.0Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 292, in function_wrapper
return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.0Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 688, in approx_fprime
return _approx_fprime_helper(xk, f, epsilon, args=args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.0Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 622, in _approx_fprime_helper
f0 = f(*((xk,) + args))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.0Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 292, in function_wrapper
return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
Exception: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

scipy's [minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) expects a callable function as first argument.

As you did not show your complete code it's just a guessing-game here, but this

```
res = minimize(-a[0], x0)
```

has to mean that the first element of *a* should be a function.

Seeing this line:

```
a = mmc.log_likelihood(2000, np.array([[0.6, 0.2, 0.8]]))
```

it does not look like that as probably a scalar is returned.

The effect is simple: scipy want's to call this given function with some argument (x0 at the beginning), but calls some numpy-array value with some argument in your case (which is not valid of course).

Answer (score 0):

Review the docs:

```
minimize(fun, x0, args=(),...
    fun : callable
        Objective function.
    x0 : ndarray
        Initial guess.
    args : tuple, optional
        Extra arguments passed to the objective function and its derivatives
```

Do you know what a 'callable' is?  It's a function (or equivalent), something can be 'called'  with `fun(x0, arg0, arg1, ...)`.

The error tells us that `-a[0]` is an element of a numpy array, `a`.

It's not clear whether you are trying to minimize this function, or whether this is part of using `minimize`.  It can't be source of `a`, because it doesn't return anything.

```
def testLLCalc():
    mmc = MortalityModelCalibrator()
    a = mmc.log_likelihood(2000, np.array([[0.6, 0.2, 0.8]]))
    # return a  ????
```

So - review your understanding of basic Python, especially the idea of a 'callable'.  And run some the `minimize` examples, to get a better feel for how to use this function.

Comment: log_likelihood is a function defined:                                                        `def log_liklihood(self, year, v):
        mm = self.create_mortality_model()
        mm.set_v(v)
        return mm.log_liklihood(self.populationData, self.deathRateData, year)`.   It was previously returning a tuple of 2 scalars, hence why I was indexing it; I've now removed one of them so it should just return the one scalar but it still isn't working.

Comment: But what function are you giving to minimize?  `function`, not scalar or tuple.

Comment: Well, the log_likelihood function which in turn returns another function which returns a scalar.

Comment: `-a[0]` might be a scalar produced directly or indirectly by `log_liklihood`, but it is not a function.